# Is it considered as a good practice to connect to two different databases in on microservice?

Tags: microservices

Is it considered as a good practice to connect to two different databases in on microservice API Or I need to implement another microservice for working with the second database and call the new microservice API inside the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing is that you have only **one microservice per database,** but it is ok to have **multiple databases per microservice** if the business case requires it.

Your microservice can abstract multiple data sources, connect them, etc. and then just give consistent api to whoever is using it. And who's using it, doesn't care how many data sources there actually is.

It becomes an issue, if you have same database abstracted by multiple microservices. Then your microservice is no longer isolated and can break, because the data source you are using was changed by another team who's using the same data source.

Comment: a bit late but if that secondary datasource is read only, this it makes sense ? the use case we have now a days is , user service is separated from other services but needed most of the times to get user properties. making http calls to user service would increase chit chat b/w services. I hope it is not an antipattern to use one primary and other read only datasources. There shouldn't be just too many.